# Error when deploying chaincode in Fabric test network

Tags: go, ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric

Environment: Fabric 2.4.2 Ubuntu20.0.4 go19.5
I've just make a directory in the work directory of minifab, and add my main.go with go.mod go.sum copied from the other chaincode sample. Then I install the code with the command "minifab ccup -n contract -l go -v 1.0 ", finally, it reports to me these error

```
# Run the chaincode install script on cli container ***********
  non-zero return code
  Error: failed to normalize chaincode path: 'go list' failed with: can't load package: package simple: 
  main.go:13:1: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:13:2: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:13:5: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:13:6: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:13:7: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:13:8: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:13:9: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:13:10: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:13:11: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:13:12: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:16:25: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:16:26: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:16:27: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:16:28: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:16:29: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:16:33: illegal UTF-8 encoding
  main.go:16:34: illegal UTF-8 encoding: exit status 1
  Error: failed to read chaincode package at 'contract_go_1.0.tar.gz': open contract_go_1.0.tar.gz: no such file or directory

# STATS *******************************************************
minifab: ok=31  failed=1
```

How can I exactly install my chaincode? What happened to it?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.
Because I have used the winscp as a tool to copy main.go go.mod go.sum into the directory, so the encode of the code has changed. As a result, the go cannot be complied.
I just touch the main.go in Xshell linking to my server, then I successs!

minifab: ok=107 failed=0